# routing nested url in react-router

Tags: reactjs

I have my routes difined, and when i navigate to `products/new`, works fine, but if refresh page, he `products/new` not enter, he returns unexpected token.

Route Config.

```
<Router history={createBrowserHistory()}>

<Route path="/" component={Layout}>
   <IndexRoute component={Home} />
   <Route path="produtos/novo" component={ProductsNew}/>
   <Route path="produtos" component={Products} />
</Route>
```

Comment: You will need to set up .htaccess or Virtual Host (if you're using Apache) to point all requests to the index page where your app is sitting.

Comment: this error occurs only in ``` products/new ```, other pages when refresh, this work fine. My server is node + express.

Comment: You do not have a route set up for  `products/new` in the code you have provided. That is probably the reason, although I'd need more information to help you...

Comment: this is my server: 

`const express = require('express')
const path = require('path')
const port = process.env.PORT || 8000
const app = express()

// serve static assets normally
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'))

// handle every other route with index.html, which will contain
// a script tag to your application's JavaScript file(s).
app.get('*', function (request, response){
  response.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'public', 'index.html'))
})

app.listen(port)
console.log("server started on port " + port)`

Comment: What happens when you navigate to `produtos/novo`?

Comment: when i navigate, clicking in link by react, works fine.

the problem ocurrs if refresh page, in this specific route.

Comment: Also in your example, you have specified the route as `produtos` and you refer to it as `products`. Is this a typo?

Comment: sorry, products = produtos.

Answer (score 3):

I ran into a similar problem and eventually realized it wasn't an issue with React Router but my own paths. It was loading files relative to `/produtos` rather than `/` (relating to your example).

I added `<base href="/" />` into the `<head>` of my `index.html` and it worked (:

Answer (score 2):

The similar question has been asked:
[Correct path for img on React.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37644265/correct-path-for-img-on-react-js)

Hopefully this will help. The key is that you use relative path from the root i.e.`'/dir/assets/xxx.xx'` the first starting `/` starts URL path form root dir.

This will be same when you work locally i.e. `http://localhost:8080/` or even on your web i.e. `http://www.yourdomain.com/`