# Serve another(standalone) page or static file in website built with react

Tags: javascript, apache, reactjs, react-router

I have a website built with react, which uses react-router. For some route I want to serve another page or static file, but since all request are forwarded to react router, its doesn't work.

for example

> www.myapp.com/sitemap.xml
>   www.myapp.com/something.html

^ these link works first time, but once i load website then it doesn't work, as all request goe through react router.

Any solution to make it work all the time. Thanks.

**Edit**

I'm using apache server which is configured to redirect all request to index.html, i guess this is the reason for this behaviour. This is my configuration, but i don't know how to fix this.

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.html [QSA,L]
```

**Update**
I tried solution suggested in answer.

my routes looks like this, for something.html i am loading ServerLoad component

```
<Switch>
    <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
    <Route path="/about" component={About} />
    <Route path="/about" component={About} />
    <Route path="something.html" component={ServerLoad} />
    <Route component={NoMatch} />
</Switch>
```

In ServerLoad component's componentDidMount function I did this. But it doesn't work.

```
componentDidMount() {
    window.location.reload(true);
}
```

**More**
I have setup this project using create-react-app, and serving it by express server([like this](https://github.com/ayroblu/ssr-create-react-app-v2/blob/master/server/app.js)). I'am not sure if i need to do some setting there to server other static files.

Comment: Did you try with a normal `<a href="/something.html"></a>` tag instead of react-router Link component?

Comment: Yes i did, even if i paste url manually (once i had loaded website) then it goes to react router and doesn't load anything.

Comment: What version of react-router are you using? I am using 3.0.5 and when I am giving it <a href> way it is working fine for me. Could you share your code snipet?

Comment: I am using react router 4. i tried setting window.href.location but thats not working

Comment: and also i'm using apache to forward all request to index file, that can be a reason also

Comment: Create a exception in your htaccess for that specific file :)

Comment: Hey @bluehipy can you point me to some post/documentation for apache configuration, because i'm not familiar how this things works

Comment: Sure http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html but from what I see in your current options, accessing a existing file should work.

Comment: it doesn't. I'm not sure whether it is apache or  react router.

Comment: so if i do www.myapp.com/something.html in incognito mode then it load properly,  but once i load www.myapp.com then after that i navigate to www.myapp.com/something.html then it doesn't works

Comment: @Abhishek it's react-router routes configuration, not apache2. But you provided no route config for react-router.

Comment: Maybe this can be a method: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37017863/1870873

Comment: You said, that calling these urls directly works, and from the web app not, It's because react router will prevent the default browser behaviour and just changes the browser history, but your links are not going to hit the webserver at all. what you have to do, is to explicitly reload the browser on the given url, check out my answer, this should work.

Comment: @Abhishek forgot to mention, `<a href="..." target="blank">Link</a>` should also work just fine..

Comment: Thanks everyone:)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This should work:

```
const reload = () => window.location.reload();

<Router>
  // all your routes..
  ...

  // Your special routes..
  <Route path="/sitemap.xml" onEnter={reload} />
  <Route path="/something.html" onEnter={reload} />
</Router>
```

So, I think this should be pretty clear what it does ;)

Update:

if this is an option you can simply put **target="_blank"** attribute in your `<Link>`

IMHO this is from the UX perspective even better, because if these routes are not part of your main application, the user can just switch the Tab after visiting that *special* pages.

Comment: Hi, I tried this, check update in question. It doesn't work

Comment: Ok So this solution works, but it might not work `properly` if you have service worker registered. Because Create-React-App support this feature out of box so it was enabled in my site. I have disabled service worker and now it works.

Comment: Thank you @webdeb

Comment: glad to help.. could you dive deeper into the problem with the service worker? Would be interesting to know whats the difference when a service worker is running..

Comment: yes i plan to do so, but right now my schedule is tight. I will update.

Comment: Where do you save the file in the project folder?
I'm trying to save at public and it's copying to the build folder, but when I serve the build it's getting 404 by react-router.

Answer (score 6):

How about simply put your statics files like `sitemap.xml` inside React's `public` folder along side index.html.

I thinks this is the easiest way.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

It's an unwanted behaviour of **ServiceWorker.js** use the comment below and change it in `index.js` of your React project (if you don't need a service worker) and it should work

```
import { unregister } from './registerServiceWorker';
unregister();
```

https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/issues/2715

If you still need a service worker and you want to avoid it having this behavior, consider installing a custom service worker, there you can establish a whitelist of paths to be ignored. For more information you can check the next link.

https://medium.com/swlh/how-to-implement-custom-service-worker-in-create-react-app-without-eject-bfa2c5f4ae96

Comment: I had the same problem, that's why I suggest this solution

Comment: Instead of unregister your service woerker you can configure it to exempt requests from being fulfilled by `index.html`.

Answer (score 1):

Use Switch combined with a `NoMatch` component, combined with webdeb's solution:

```
<Router>
  <div>
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
      <Route exact path="/admin" component={Admin} />
      <Route component={NoMatch} />
      <Route onEnter={() => window.location.reload()} />
    </Switch>
  </div>
</Router>
```

This will match routes, show 404 if no valid href exists, and show a file or something if it's a valid href.

Answer (score 1):

If you need `/terms` to redirect to `/terms.html`, the code below worked for me with **react-router 3.x**.

```
const reload = () => window.location.reload();
<Router>
  <Switch>
    <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />                
    <Route path="/terms.html" render={reload} />
    <Route path="/privacy.html" render={reload} />
    <Route path="/terms" render={() => <Redirect
        to={{
          pathname: "/terms.html"
        }}
      />} 
    />
    <Route path="/privacy" render={() => <Redirect
        to={{
          pathname: "/privacy.html"
        }}
      />} 
    />
  </Switch>
</Router>
```

Answer (score 0):

**1. Create folders for each HTML file inside the public folder.**

[image]

**2. Add route paths (path= name_of_folder_contained_static_file)**

[image]

**3. Call route paths as you want :)**

Demo:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: In case you are interested in replacing localhost with your domain. You can directly use `window.location.href = process.env.PUBLIC_URL + '/aboutstat'` in your component itself.

Answer (score -2):

If the pages are unrelated to the Reactjs App at all(i.e. using another directory), I think we can route it from Node layer using the following code, so that the structure is more intuitive:

```
app.use('/url_to_static_pages', express.static('path_to_static_files'));
```

Comment: OP didn't mention anything about using node