# Is there a way to link non-react html files in a react app?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

Let's say I have a react application hosted at example.com. Now, I already have a very simple html/js website that I want to display at example.com/example. I can easily do this if I rewrite the website in react, but I don't want to do that because the html/js website is so simple and it would be unnecessary to be written in react.

Is there any way I can directly put and link this html/js website with the rest of my project?

Comment: https://medium.com/@justintulk/serving-static-html-into-a-react-component-using-node-express-8cb9fc9194df this may help you, though serving static HTML pages using the react way really isn't that much overhead (and looks better), but there's nothing wrong with having node serve up a static dir

Comment: What is your back end for the react project?

Comment: React is just a JavaScript library, same as, let's say, jQuery. You can even have a different framework for each page (eg. index.html can be React, example.html can be vanilla JS, test.html can be Angular). You can even all of them on the same page.

Comment: This might help you for the same. https://stackoverflow.com/a/45936690/11253427

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create React app with `create-react-app` you have the following filesystem structure:

```
my-app/
 README.md
 node_modules/
 package.json
 public/
   index.html
   custom-page.html <-- Create custom page
   favicon.ico
 src/
   App.css
   App.js
   App.test.js
   index.css
   index.js
   logo.svg
```

https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/folder-structure

So, you can just create any static pages in `/public` directory and reference them. All the resources in `/public` directory will be available in the root of your website.

For example, `custom-page.html` will be accessible by http://localhost:3000/custom-page.html.