# Opening HTML Files from a [src] Sub-folder in a single-page React App (Routing?)

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am making a Single-Page React App [website]. Therefore, most of the links are on the same page, with ID #s, and that works fine for now.

The WIP present version of this particular app in question can be found here, for reference:
https://iworks.netlify.app/

In the Footer component, I have made a 'Legal' links' UL with Copyright, Privacy Policy and TOS, as standard HTML Files. These three basic HTML Files are placed in a sub-folder in the SRC folder itself, in production. This sub-folder is named 'html', and the links are set to open in a new tab.

The question is, how do I make React to recognise and build this sub-folder in the app, and to open these links relatively?

[Since these pages are not 'built' into the app, they certainly do not get included in the Build either. Now, one simple solution is definitely to just put them manually into the build, later on; but I also want to learn the fool-proof method to do this correctly. Hence this enquiry.]

Most of the discussions relating to React Routing on the web seem to either specify multi-page apps, setting components to open separately; or to place the entire react app in a sub-folder. However, I just want to manage these three links (i.e. HTML pages in 'html' sub-folder) as independent entities (for now).

What would be the most efficient manner to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Duplicate of [Is there a way to link non-react html files in a react app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55346181/is-there-a-way-to-link-non-react-html-files-in-a-react-app)

Just place your html files inside the `public` folder of you create-react-app application.
If you are not using cra, just place the html files in the folder of your web server set up to serve static content.