# Correct path for img on React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I have some problem with my images on my react project. Indeed I always thought that relative path into src attribute was built on the files architecture

Here my files architecture:

```
components
    file1.jsx
    file2.jsx
    file3.jsx
container
img
js 
...
```

However I realized that the path is built on the url. In one of my component (for example into file1.jsx) I have this:

```
localhost/details/2
<img src="../img/myImage.png" /> -> works

localhost/details/2/id
<img src="../img/myImage.png" /> -> doesn't work, images are not displayed
```

How is it possible to solve this problem? I want that in any form of routes handled by react-router, all images can be displayed with the same path.

Comment: just point directly to the image, dont use ../ whatever

Comment: You need to use `require`. Read this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34583854/2099607) on SO for more info.

Comment: Hope this answer helps you out
[React local images](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61783390/11225762)

Answer (score 98, accepted):

You're using a relative url, which is relative to the current url, not the file system.  You could resolve this by using absolute urls

`<img src ="http://localhost:3000/details/img/myImage.png" />`

But that's not great for when you deploy to www.my-domain.bike, or any other site.  Better would be to use a url relative to the root directory of the site

`<img src="/details/img/myImage.png" />`

Comment: Thanks, I would emphasize the `/` that precedes `details` (vs `./details`, etc, for others who may conflate the two).

Comment: Even for me it's not working. I am using `reactjs` with `cordova` and using `ES5` as eslint

Comment: While both this and claireablani's solution work, claireablani's is what the create-react-app docs recommend.  They list a number of benefits over putting the resources in public https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/using-the-public-folder#adding-assets-outside-of-the-module-system

Comment: @user1322092 is right. Remember it's `/images/popcorn.png` and not `./images/popcorn.png`. Worked for me with all the routes and stuff.

Comment: the / will follow the component url, not work

Comment: like @Dima mentioned below, if you used `create-react-app` then you can place the images in `public->myImgFolder->myImg.png` folder and use it as `<img src="/myImgFolder/myImg.png" alt={"logo"}/>`

Comment: rainversion_3 it is work dude

Answer (score 473):

In `create-react-app` relative paths for images don't seem to work. Instead, you can import an image:

```
import logo from './logo.png' // relative path to image 

class Nav extends Component { 
    render() { 
        return ( 
            <img src={logo} alt={"logo"}/> 
        )  
    }
}
```

Comment: what about dynamic images, for instance, referenced in a json file, in create-react-app?

Comment: @zok I think you would export the variable from the JSON file, import the variable into your component. Then you can reference it as usual. e.g. export const my_src = variable_here, import {my_src} from my_file, and src={my_src}.

Comment: `import './styles/style.less';
**import logo from './styles/images/deadline.png';**` I am getting error on 2nd line module not found while image exists & path is correct.

Comment: This method is also confirmed by by [survive.js](https://survivejs.com/webpack/loading/images/#referencing-to-images) if you want to take a look at one of the core webpack author's methods. He also mentions you can use [babel-plugin-transform-react-jsx-img-import](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-transform-react-jsx-img-import) to get around having to import the image every time you reference an image.

Comment: Not this, it solves only image issue but does not solve the path issue.. Dima Gershman' answer is the actual react solution for path of any file img or else

Comment: This is the best practice for me who used for dummy image which located in the same root folder

Comment: In my case, Even json file is dynamic and logo can we fetched from either A or B file depends on condition. How can solve this case with your approach?
FYI: I don't want to use multiple import because we have many client lets say 1000, in that case if we go with this approach we will end up using import statement 1000 times! for using logo conditionally.

Comment: Check [create-react-app/adding-images..](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-images-fonts-and-files/) documentation for more.

Answer (score 229):

If you used create-react-app to create your project then your public folder is accessible. So you need to add your `image` folder inside the public folder.

> public/images/

`<img src="/images/logo.png" />`

Comment: It worked for me. Just remember that you need to restart the app if you added new image to the public directory.

Comment: It is indeed a fast way to treat the situations, but it will work only if you don't need relative URLs. E.g. if you serve your app at `www.example.com/react-app`, the public folder will be exposed on www.example.com, without `react-app`. This can be troublesome, so the accepted answer is the correct one. Sources: [adding assets](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-images-fonts-and-files/) and [using public folder](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/using-the-public-folder/)

Answer (score 75):

With `create-react-app` there is **public** folder (with **index.html**...). 
If you place your "myImage.png" there, say under **img** sub-folder, then you can access them through:

```
<img src={window.location.origin + '/img/myImage.png'} />
```

Comment: This should be marked as the correct answer, because it is actually reactjs solution for all types of paths of any files

Comment: I don't understand why you think this is the correct answer. I just tried this answer and Claireblani's answer and claire's answer worked while this did not. This answer only works if the image is in the public folder. Should my images go in the public folder? @Sami

Comment: Yes @Maderas first things is is this answer is same as the accepted one => just removing {} and base url you can use simply src='/relative path of image' or src='absolute path of image'

Whats more in this answer is that it accommodates variable path for any image

Comment: So far works for me like a charm. Nothing else did! And I tried just about everything. Thanks!

Answer (score 48):

If the image is placed inside the 'src' folder, use the following:

```
<img src={require('../logo.png')} alt="logo" className="brand-logo"/>
```

Comment: That worked for me. This works in the case you DON'T want to store images in public folder

Comment: For anyone facing [object Module] error in the img's src, do this ```src={require('../logo.png').default}```

Comment: This works for `.csv` files as well. A great help.

Answer (score 41):

1. Make an images folder inside src(/src/images) And keep your image in it. Then import this image in your component(use your relative path). Like below-

   `import imageSrc from './images/image-name.jpg';`

   And then in your component.

   `<img title="my-img" src={imageSrc} alt="my-img" />`
2. Another way is to keep images in public folder and import them using relative path. For this make an image folder in public folder and keep your image in it. And then in your component use it like below.

   `<img title="my-img" src='/images/my-image.jpg' alt="my-img" />`

   Both method work but first one is recommended because its cleaner way and images are handled by webpack during build time.

Comment: This won't work, a slash ( / ) is required at the start to indicate relative path, like so: "/images/pitbull-mark.png"

Comment: have you tried the one mentioned in the answer? This should work too.

Comment: @JeremyRea A slash at the start indicates an absolute path, not a relative path.

Answer (score 21):

Some older answers din't work, others are good but won't explain the theme, in summary:

## If image is in 'public' directory

Example: `\public\charts\a.png`

In html:

```
<img id="imglogo" src="/charts/logo.svg" />
```

In JavaScript:

Create image to new img, dynamically:

```
var img1 = document.createElement("img");  
img1.src = 'charts/a.png';
```

Set image to existing img with id as 'img1', dynamically:

```
document.getElementById('img1').src = 'charts/a.png';
```

## If image is in 'src' directory:

Example: `\src\logo.svg`

In JavaScript:

```
import logo from './logo.svg';  
img1.src = logo;
```

In jsx:

```
<img src={logo} />
```

Answer (score 10):

I have used it this way and it worked perfectly

```
import Product from "../../images/product-icon.png";
import { Icon } from "@material-ui/core";

<Icon>
    <img src={Product} style={{ width: "21px", height: "24px" }} />
</Icon>
```

Answer (score 5):

Adding [file-loader npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/file-loader) to webpack.config.js per its official usage instruction like so:

```
config.module.rules.push(
    {
        test: /\.(png|jpg|gif)$/,
        use: [
            {
                loader: 'file-loader',
                options: {}
            }
        ]
    }
);
```

worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

Import Images in your component

```
import RecentProjectImage_3 from '../../asset/image/recent-projects/latest_news_3.jpg'
```

And call the image name on image *src={RecentProjectImage_3}* as a object

```
 <Img src={RecentProjectImage_3} alt="" />
```

Answer (score 2):

A friend showed me how to do this as follows:

"./" works when the file requesting the image (e.g., "example.js") is on the same level within the folder tree structure as the folder "images".

Answer (score 1):

Place the logo in your public folder under e.g. public/img/logo.png and then refer to the public folder as %PUBLIC_URL%:

```
<img src="%PUBLIC_URL%/img/logo.png"/>
```

The use of %PUBLIC_URL% in the above will be replaced with the URL of the `public` folder during the build. Only files inside the `public` folder can be referenced from the HTML.

Unlike "/img/logo.png" or "logo.png", "%PUBLIC_URL%/img/logo.png" will work correctly both with client-side routing and a non-root public URL. Learn how to configure a non-root public URL by running `npm run build`.

Answer (score 0):

If your page url contains multiple / then in `src` go back `/` count minus 1 times.

For example page url `http://localhost:3000/play/game/` then `src` url must be `../your-image-folder/image-name`. And your `your-image-folder` must be in `public` folder.

Answer (score 0):

I create my app with **create-react-app** and I use **require** instruction if I want to change dynamically my image src:

```
export const MyComponent = () => {
  const [myImg, setMyImg] = useState(require('./path/to/my/img'));

  const handleClick = () => {
    setMyImg(require('./path/to/other/img'));
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <img src={myImg} alt='myImg' />
      <button onClick={handleClick}>Click me!<button/>
    <div>
  )
}
```