# Import image dynamically in React component

Tags: reactjs, image, import

I have an Articles component that shows a blog page with listed articles.

```
render() {
    const articles = {
        ...this.state.articles
    }

    const article = Object.keys(articles).map(cur => {
        return <Article
            key={this.state.articles[cur].id}
            imgName={this.state.articles[cur].thumb}
            title={this.state.articles[cur].title}
            meta={this.state.articles[cur].meta}
            clicked={() => this.detailedHandler(this.state.articles[cur].id)}
            detailed={this.state.articles[cur].detailed} />
    });
```

As you can see I pass image name with props to Article component.
I want then to display the appropriate image for each article.

How do I import an image in Article component based on the props I receive (props.imgName) from Articles component?

Comment: The image name would need to then be added to the end of a url string where you have stored the image on a server. Then pllaced as the src to an html `<img src=https://myWebsite.com/images/${this.prop.imgName}.jpg />`

Comment: I have my images in src/assets folder. And if I understand correctly after webpack builds the project these images name and path are changed. So I cant use relative url like that

Answer (score 23):

I used context.

```
const images = require.context('../../../assets/img', true);
loadImage = imageName => (assets(`./${imageName}`).default);
<img src={loadImage("someimage.png")} alt="" />
```

I don't know if this is an optimal solution, but it works.

Comment: Inline image is injected in this case that cause performance issues.

Comment: This code does not make sense. Where did you get `assets` function? What's `require.context`? `require` doesn't have any `context` in it

Comment: @JerryGreen It is a webpack function
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54059179/what-is-require-context

Comment: Instead of using ```loadImage = imageName => (assets(`./${imageName}`).default);``` you can use this ```const loadImage = imageName => (images(`./${imageName}`).default);```

Answer (score 20):

For anyone looking for a modern approach using async-await and custom react hooks, I found a pretty slick solution. Create a file called `useImage.js` and paste the following code:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react'

const useImage = (fileName) => {
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true)
    const [error, setError] = useState(null)
    const [image, setImage] = useState(null)

    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchImage = async () => {
            try {
                const response = await import(`../assets/img/${fileName}`) // change relative path to suit your needs
                setImage(response.default)
            } catch (err) {
                setError(err)
            } finally {
                setLoading(false)
            }
        }

        fetchImage()
    }, [fileName])

    return {
        loading,
        error,
        image,
    }
}

export default useImage
```

Then just import the custom hook into your image component, mine looks something like this:

```
import useImage from '../../hooks/useImage'

import Typography from './Typography' // simple plain-text react component

const Image = ({ fileName, alt, className, ...rest }) => {
    const { loading, error, image } = useImage(fileName)

    if (error) return <Typography>{alt}</Typography>

    return (
        <>
            {loading ? (
                <Typography>loading</Typography>
            ) : (
                <img
                    className={`Image${
                        className
                            ? className.padStart(className.length + 1)
                            : ''
                    }`}
                    src={image}
                    alt={alt}
                    {...rest}
                />
            )}
        </>
    )
}

export default Image
```

The nice thing about this solution is that no matter where your component is in relation to your assets folder, the react hook is always in the same place, so the relative path stays the same.

Comment: This is working very well. I'm not using the Typography class, so I just have ```if (error) return {alt};``` However, when the file name is wrong, I get error "Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {alt}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead."

Comment: I just got the file error case to work by adding useEffect to error case like so: ```useEffect(() => {if (error != null) {return {alt};}}, [alt, error]);```

Answer (score 19):

You can load images dynamically from the API response with `dynamic imports` that is [Stage 3 proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-dynamic-import) as of now.

The resulting code should look something like:

```
loadImage = imageName => {
  import(`./assets/${imageName}.jpg`).then(image => {
    this.setState({
      image
    });
  });
};
render() {
  const { image } = this.state;
  return (
    <Fragment>
      {image && <img src={image} alt="" />}
    </Fragment>
  );
}
```

[View Codesandbox Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/40r1nrvm79)

This feature is supported out of the box in [`create-react-app`](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/code-splitting), If using other systems, you can use the [Babel plugin](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-syntax-dynamic-import)

Comment: `React.lazy` is used for importing components, so you would have to import the image into a component first

Comment: Now this would be the most correct answer I think. This could be used to include assets like images, or services or modules in our final build depending on an environment variable, which is nice and just what I need. Do you know if it's possible to import all images of given a path, I mean, load all images in first component? Thank you.

Comment: @sevenlops I would normally use an [import-all.macro](https://github.com/kentcdodds/import-all.macro) in that scenario

Comment: you probably missed `image.default`

Comment: Oops... The Codesandbox Demo does not exist anymore!

Comment: This is the best aproach. Just to share my experience, you need to write the import with the text of the image like in the answer. It doesn't work with a constant like this: ```const name = `./assets/${imageName}.jpg` import(name)```. Still trying to figure out why this does not work.

Answer (score 4):

there are my way, works nicely:)

> ```
> import React, {useState} from "react"
>
> const getFavorites = (props) => {
>
>   const {item, favouritesNote} = props;
>   const [image, setImage] = useState("");
>
>   (function (imageName) {
>     import(
>       `../../../../assets/images/chart/favorite${imageName ? "_active" : ""}.png`
>     ).then((image) => setImage(image.default));
>   })(favouritesNote[item.id]);
>
>   return (
>     <div>{image && <img alt="" className="img-responsive" src={image} />}</div
>   )
> }
> ```

Comment: Great answer! I think if you will change the variable name from favouritesNote to imageSrc it will be more clear.

Answer (score 1):

**Note**: All these comments work complementary with the @jadenRose hook solution which is a great abstraction.

You can import the images dynamically with the native js dynamic `import('')` , there's no need for React Lazy.

However, you have to be aware of the path/content you pass to the `import(path)` because depending on how you are planning to include the images to import in the final bundle there could be restrictions. There are two main ways:

**Note**: This is for Rollup, in Webpack i didn't try it but should be similar

a)- Making rollup automatically include the possibles files to import while creating the bundle using the official plugin https://www.npmjs.com/package/@rollup/plugin-dynamic-import-vars please read the doc and notice how there are important restrictions in the 'path' string, essentially you should just set the file name in the variable, the rest of the path have to be fixed in the import('') in order to provide rollup a restricted scope to import. eg:

**OK**

`import(`../assets/img/${fileName}.svg`)`

**Wrong**

`import(filePath)`

b)- Include in the bundle programmatically the files you can dynamically import example

```
//rollup.config.js 
import copy from 'rollup-plugin-copy';

plugins: [
    copy({
        targets: [ { src: 'src/assets/icons/*', dest: 'lib/assets/icons' },],
    }),
           …        
],
```

With this option b) you have no restrictions on the variable content but have to be careful with what you included in the bundle.

**Conclusion**: You can use dynamic `import(...)` but if you not properly handle the files inclusion on the bundle, it can be possible they are excluded and then the dynamic import will fail in the consumer.

Answer (score 0):

I found this worked best for me:
I created an index file inside the images folder. there I imported all the images I have and created a class component with the variables assigned to each image import. this is because when we import an image in react using the import statement, that is,  `import someImage from './somewhere'` react assigns the 'someImage' variable to a module with a *'static media' address*, my terminology there might be wrong. Here is the example:

```
import image13_1 from './image13_1.png';
import image13_2 from './image13_2.png';
import image13_3 from './image13_3.png';
import image13_4 from './image13_4.png';
import image13_5 from './image13_5.png';
import image13_6 from './image13_6.png';
import image13_7 from './image13_7.png';

export class IMG{

    1= image13_1

    2 = image13_2

    3 = image13_3

    4 = image13_4

    5 = image13_5

    6 = image13_6

    7 = image13_7

  }
  export default IMG;
```

from here I just import the IMG class and create an instance of it and call the image number a property:

```
var img = new IMG()
console.log('img',img[1]
```

Comment: This won't work if you have no access to the **images** folder. You might be accessing the images from an API, for example.

Comment: User asked for dynamic importing. This images are stablished beforehand. No dynamic here.