# Add a custom script to package.json in create-react-app project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, create-react-app

What I want to do is add a custom script in `package.json` file that should run **always** before `start` and `build` scripts.

Things I want to do in my custom script:

- Copy the favicon.ico file from `/favicons/${process.env.REACT_APP_BRAND}.ico` into `/public`, in order to overwrite the default one
- Do a symlink from `/src/assets/${process.env.REACT_APP_BRAND}` to `/src/assets/brand`, in order to import images inside code without doing things like [dynamic imports](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53777456) (which works but I think it's not their purpose)

I'm a bit lost with the structure of this custom script, and programming languange (its shell, but I'm on MacOS, so, it's better do it in node?)

Thank you.

Comment: Why don't you simply add a custom script in package.json and then reference it first thing in your `start` and `build` scripts? For example, `start: myOtherScript ...`

Comment: @BThuy yes but I'm newbie with npm (not with JS) and I don't know how to start, only I know that is possible. For example: this `myOtherScript`, where has to be placed? And with which language? I only want to do file changes, so Bash script can be done here? or it's better do it in JS in order to be platform agnostic (aka windows)? I just want a simple example, some entry point, BEST PRACTICES...

Comment: npm scripts run in your executing console and inherit its environment variables and such. So, you can add a script `myOtherScript: "echo 'myOtherScript'"` and use it like this: `start: "npm run myOtherScript && myStartScript"`

Comment: Just so you know: `npm start` is a predefined alias for `npm run start`. Every script defined in `package.json` can be called with `npm run [script-name]`