# Using in image tag in react with a image url imported from a json file

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, json

I'm trying to make a simple blog page where I can read the blogs from a JSON file, and then proceed to upload them to the site.

**Blog.jsx**

```
import React from 'react'
import BYFDC from '../global/BYFDC'
import blogs from './Blogs.json'

function Blog() {
  return (
    <div className='mt-[15vh]'>
        <div>
            <h1 className='text-4xl text-center items-center justify-center flex py-16 text-[#398492]'>
                YourCareerStrategy Blog
            </h1>
            <div className='flex items-center justify-center'>
              <img src={require(`${blogs[0].image}`)} alt='Blog' />
              <h1 className='text-center items-center justify-center flex py-16 '>
                {blogs[0].name} 
              </h1>
            </div>
            <div>
              <BYFDC />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Blog
```

**Blogs.json**

```
[
    {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "Blog Three",
        "desc": "A little description for blog three",
        "image": "../../assets/images/Eli.png"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Blog Two",
        "desc": "A little description for blog two",
        "image": "../../assets/images/Eli.png"
    },
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Blog One",
        "desc": "A little description for blog one",
        "image": "../../assets/images/Eli.png"
    }
]
```

I've tried many things to get the `` <img src={require(`${blogs[0].image}`)} alt='Blog' /> `` to actually display an image, but nothing seems to work. Some stuff break the whole page, others make it go to the alt text... regardless, it never works.
Keep in mind I know I can import the image in the file or whatever, I just want to make it so I can edit the json file, and thats all the work i need to do to make a new blog, so I dont want imports for images inside the jsx file.

I tried using
`` <img src={require(`${blogs[0].image}`)} alt='Blog' /> ``
`<img src={require(blogs[0].image)} alt='Blog' />`
`<img src={require(blogs[0].image).default} alt='Blog' />`
`<img src={blogs[0].image} alt='Blog' />`
`` <img src={`${blogs[0].image}`} alt='Blog' /> ``

I think a few more, thats what I could remember

Comment: Try to useEffect to print out the blogs to see if they are imported correctly.

Comment: They are imported correctly, I the blogs[0].name works just fine, the error is coming from the image.

Comment: Try `import` instead of `require` as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70024111/863110)

Comment: Doesnt worth either, defaults to the alt name... and yes the path in the json file is correct, I copy and pasted it into the src and it worked fine