# Insert image path into react

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to insert an image default inside my html using jQuery. I don't know why, but the path doesn't work.
If the image-detail is 404 I have to use a default image. 
The image is called img-default.png and it is inside /public

this is the code:

```
         fetch('url')
          .then(function (response) {
            return response.json();
          }).then(function (data) {
            const img_detail = data['img-detail']
            if (data['img-detail'] == 404) {
              console.log('error on load image')
              const img_default = 'http://localhost:3001/myproject/public/img-default.png' // not work :(
              //apply to div content
             $('#content').css({ 'background-image': 'url(' + img_default + ')' });
            } else {
             $('#content').css({ 'background-image': 'url(' + img_detail + ')' });
          }).catch(function () {
             console.log("Error al traer la imagen");
          });
```

Why doesn't it work?
Thanks!

Comment: Can you access the image link directly in the browser?
http://localhost:3001/myproject/public/img-default.png

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I reference a local image in React?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39999367/how-do-i-reference-a-local-image-in-react)

Comment: varoons.. nop, i cant