# ReactJS Load Picture from Project, doesnt work somehow

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i got a simple problem which i cant resolve,
i got an "array" which contains and "array" where i want to display the first Picture,

heres the code:

```js
                        {Skills.map((item, index) => 
                            <Window key={index} className="col-md-3 m-2 ">
                                <CardFrame className="cardFrame-max cardFrame-size-md">
                                    <div className="row justify-items-center">
                                        <div className="col-8 offset-2">
                                            <p className="battle-shonen-color">{"Skill Name: " + item.name}</p>
                                            <img src={require('../../' + item.effects[0].icon)}></img>
                                            <p className="battle-shonen-color">{"Skill Shortcode: " + item.shortcode}</p>
                                            <p className="battle-shonen-color">{"Skill Description: " + item.quote}</p>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </CardFrame> 
                            </Window>
                        )}
```

its at the  tag where it shows me the error: 
"Error: Cannot find module './resources/img/icon/effects/Damage.png'" ,

so it does load the string saved in the array but doesnt add '../../' infront

Comment: This may help https://stackoverflow.com/a/39999421/6865416

Answer (score 0, accepted):

---

```
    {require(`../../${item.effects[0].icon}`)}
```

Comment: Still same as above: Error: Cannot find module './resources/img/icon/effects/Damage.png'

Comment: @Terraya what exactly is {  item.effects[0].icon } ?

Comment: its a path "/resources/img/icon/Damage.png"

Comment: {require(`../..${item.effects[0].icon}`)}

Answer (score 0):

Can you try like this

```
 {Skills.map((item, index) => 
                            <Window key={index} className="col-md-3 m-2 ">
                                <CardFrame className="cardFrame-max cardFrame-size-md">
                                    <div className="row justify-items-center">
                                        <div className="col-8 offset-2">
                                            <p className="battle-shonen-color">{"Skill Name: " + item.name}</p>
                                            <img src={require(`../../${item.effects[0].icon}`)}></img>
                                            <p className="battle-shonen-color">{"Skill Shortcode: " + item.shortcode}</p>
                                            <p className="battle-shonen-color">{"Skill Description: " + item.quote}</p>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </CardFrame> 
                            </Window>
                        )}
 Run code snippet
```

Comment: Already have tryed it, still getting same : Error: Cannot find module './resources/img/icon/effects/Damage.png'

Answer (score 0):

import your images in your items file.
e.g. :

```
import ImageName from '../../whatever.jpg';
```

and use it in your items array.

```
[
  {
    icon: ImageName
  }
]
```

Comment: Yes that approach wouldnt be bad but since i load the images from a Database Object, i wouldnt do that since its not recommendet :s

Comment: if you load it from database, How it is in your react project? if you load in your app to have to set address from built files. e.g. the images load in /img/ folder in production mode.

Comment: Yes well, lets say , the Files are Stored in the Project Localy but the Database Object have stored the "Path" to the Stored file

Comment: so as I said, see where assets path is in production and set your path in DB base on it.