# How could I put my background image behind a Navbar in react?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-navigation, navbar

I'm trying to put a background image behind my Navbar in react. The end result should look something like this: https://www.salient.com/. I've tried setting the navbar background to be `none` and `transparent`, both resulting with it not working. I also tried putting my background image and my navbar in one div, but they are still separated.

This is my main `App.js` file:

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <Router>
          <NavigationBar />
          <Switch>
              <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
              <Route path="/projects" component={Projects} />
              <Route path="/contact" component={Contact} />
          </Switch>
        </Router>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

And this is my `Home.js` (I use `App.js` for stuff that I want to be on all pages, and separate files like `Home.js` or `Project.js` for specific pages, pretty new to react so im new to all of this):

```
class Home extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                (putting an image here puts the image under the nav bar, not as a background image)
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Home;
```

This is the Navbar ("NavigationBar"):

```
export const NavigationBar = () => (
    <Styles>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-light navbar-dark imageWrapper">
            <ul class="links">
                <li>
                    <a class="nav-link" href="/">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a class="nav-link" href="/projects">Projects</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a class="nav-link" href="/contact">Contact</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </Styles>
)
```

Currently, my react app looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yzdQ9.png).

Any sort help/advice is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Use these styles to your image and its wrapped div tag. It should make it position to the top
You need to make sure that the Image is inside the nav component to position it accordingly.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-light navbar-dark imageWrapper">
            <ul class="links">
                <li>
                    <a class="nav-link" href="/">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a class="nav-link" href="/projects">Projects</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a class="nav-link" href="/contact">Contact</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <div className="img"></div>
        </nav>


nav.imageWrapper{
    position: relative
}

nav.imageWrapper div.img { position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: 0;
    max-height: 70vh;
    background-size: cover;
background: url('../images/background.jpg');
z-index: -1
}
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-kliqc3?file=index.js (check this example)

Comment: I will update the code to show what are the changes i've made. Sadly, it still isn't working. Now my background image isn't even appearing.

Comment: please add the background to show up
I have edited my answer to include the image in the css

Comment: I have updated the image. I put the line: `background: '../images/background.jpg'` on the first update already, but it still doesn't show anything...

Comment: @alexholstv - please check the stackblitz example

Comment: The background css isn't loading in the example. Can't really tell if that's gonna work.

Comment: also, just realized, I can't put `<div className="img"><d/iv>` in the navbar since I don't want it to be on all pages that have a navbar.

Comment: I think I'd need to allow the navbar to allow background images or something like that, instead of putting images in a navbar

Comment: you can condition that on the page where you load the component

Comment: Yeah, I put the nav bar only on the pages I want, but now I need to add the background image only in the homepage. I though of making to separate navbars, one for the home page and one for the rest of the pages, but that's not really efficient.

Comment: Could you explain what you meant by "condition that on the page where you load the component"?

Comment: I have updated the stackblitz with conditional image render using a flag.
@alexholstv

Comment: Van Run, still css not loading, but I will still try to use the code to see if maybe it works for me.

Comment: @alexholstv you should be able to see the output now - I have forked it

Comment: Hey again. Nothing working, the background image isn't loading in the stackblitz example, and when I copy to mine, it doesn't work either.

Comment: When I head over to the console on stackblitz, it gives an error something like: "Failed to load image.jpg". So I decided to see if copying the code to my project would work, but no.

Answer (score 0):

Local image imports work somewhat differently in React due to how it's bundled. The image here may not be loading correctly. I would recommend changing the import to look like this:

```
nav.imageWrapper div.img { 
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 0;
  max-height: 70vh;
  background-size: cover;
  background-image: url('../images/background.jpg'); //replace background, wrap in URL reference
}
```

If you're having trouble importing images directly too you can read more at [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39999367/how-do-i-reference-a-local-image-in-react).

Comment: Hey! I used the import like that: `background-image: url('../images/background.jpg');`, but it's still not working (not loading the image). By the way, thanks for posting an answer!

Comment: I think I found something interesting: inspecting element shows that there is a div `div class="img"></div>`. Which makes me think maybe react is only loading the image in the navigation bar area (or it is really the css issue). I don't know really, just to point it out.