# Having issues with my img src using React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, src, imgsource

I'm trying to use an image of a search icon on my site, but it's not loading. I keep making sure my directory to the image is correct and it all looks good to me. I am currently in my Navbar>Index.js file and trying to get to my folder assets/icons/search.png

```
                    <img src={require('../../assets/icons/search.png')} alt="Search" />
```

[my directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qc7wb.png)

[image not loading on my site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/21maE.png)

Comment: I think this is similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39999367/how-do-i-reference-a-local-image-in-react
Are you using webpack? Only then you need to use require, otherwise you can directly provide the path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In React you have to first import the image before you can use it.

```
import Image from '../../assets/icons/search.png'
```

Then you can use it like this

```
<img src={Image} alt="Search" />
```