# Why my picture does not appear, seeing only the alt?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to display a pic inside a card but it does not work... actually I only see instead of the pic the attribute alt but I don't see the pic...

Here is my code :

```
import React, {Component} from "react";
import classes from "./cards.css"

const Cards = (props) => {
    return (
        <>
            <div  id="card" className={"card text-white bg-info mb-3"}
                 style={{maxWidth: 200, marginRight: 10}}>
                <div className="card-header">Test</div>
                    <img src="myPicture.jpg" className="card-img-top" alt="pic" />
                <div className="card-body">
                    <h4 className="card-title">This is a test</h4>
                </div>
            </div>
        </>
    )
}

export default Cards;
```

Do you know how can I do to see my pic on my card ?

Thank you a lot for your help !

Comment: It's showing the `alt` text because it's not loading. We'll need more information about your configuration in order to troubleshoot. You should also be getting an error for this.

Comment: Probably the path to the image inside `src` is wrong.

Comment: Try this, might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39999367/how-do-i-reference-a-local-image-in-react

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked that the image has loaded correctly?  You can use the inspector 'network' tab.  Make sure the image is being loaded by the page.  It will likely be red if it is not found (in the inspector).

Answer (score 0):

If you're using webpack, try this:

```
import backgroundImage from './myPicture.jpg';

// all other code

return (
 <div>
  <img src={backgroundImage} alt="Background image" className="image" />
 </div>
)
```

Config required in webpack:

```
module.exports = {
 // other config
 module: {
  rules: [
    // other rules
    {
        test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|svg)$/,
        loader: 'file-loader'
    },
  ]
 }
}
```

You need to install [file-loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/file-loader) package

Answer (score -1):

Add this

```
import BackgroundImage from './myPicture.jpg';
    
<img src="{require('./myPicture.jpg')}" className="card-img-top"alt="pic" />
```