# Image is not loading in server side rendering with react

Tags: reactjs, jsx, create-react-app, server-side-rendering, react-dom-server

I'm doing server-side rendering with React DOM Server using Create React App. I'm trying to load a static image but it's not showing up in my browser. Here is my app.js code

```
import './App.css';
import React from "react";
import Pic from './Images/pic.png'
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <img src={Pic} />
    </div>
  );
}
export default App;
```

The image is copied into the build folder but it's not showing up in the browser
[Folder hierarchy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UUxsn.png)

I get the following  error in the browser

```
GET http://localhost:8000/[object%20Object]
```

Comment: Please check the following https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39999367/how-do-i-reference-a-local-image-in-react

Comment: What does `Pic` contain? `console.log` setting a debugger breakpoint should help.

Comment: on console.log it displays empty curly braces "{}".

Comment: I assume that you either run your server directly (without webpack) or your webpack.config.js is not configured correctly for image imports. If you have a webpack.config.js, show it so we can help you next. If you just run your server directly, I suggested that you should run it through webpack with a suitable config for your need. Let me know further if you need help setting this up.

Answer (score 0):

**Try**

```
<img src={require(./Images/pic.png)} width="100" height="50" />
```

Comment: I am using jsx. I have tired this and it doesn't work out. :(

Comment: src={window.location.origin + '/Images/pic.png'}

Comment: as I am using a node app so window object will not work in this case. It will work in browser's console. I tired it in browser it displayed path in console "http://localhost:8000/Images/pic.png".