# How to properly refer an image from a folder in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

so my app.js is in src folder, and I am trying to access an image in the src/images folder.
I am trying with:

```
<div><ImgMediaCard name='../images/image.png'/></div>
```

but it is not working, it will only work if I place the image in the same folder as app.js

```
<div><ImgMediaCard name='../image.png'/></div>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I reference a local image in React?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39999367/how-do-i-reference-a-local-image-in-react)

Comment: @lissettdm it really doesnt, I tried checking a lot of threads before and nothing worked

Comment: How is ImgMediaCard implemented?

Comment: Apparently I can only refer to files in public folder, so I had to place the image there and it appeared. not sure why

Answer (score 0):

Did you using create-react app?

you can put your images folder inside public folder

```
//-publc
// -images
//  -image.png

<div><ImgMediaCard name='/images/image.png'/></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

if your image doesn't have in the public folder so you need to import

```
import myImage from '../images/image.png';

<div><ImgMediaCard name={myImage}/></div>
```