# How to create relative path in React so images appear

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I was having a problem in my React app, where after going through a  or  the images would not show up. The CSS is defined, and the console shows a 500 error, although I have the pictures etc. Some of the code is like this;

```
          <img className="baner" src="/..img/icons/sold-out.png" alt="Item Sold Out"></img>
```

and some like this

```
        <img className="medium" src={product.image} alt={product.name} />
```

after doing some research, I found adding a / to the beinning of the path works. For example;

```
          <img className="baner" src="/../img/icons/sold-out.png" alt="Item Sold Out"></img>
```

That said, I do not how to add this into the second example, or that it would actually even work.  Trying;

```
        <img className="medium" src=/{product.image} alt={product.name} />
```

produces errors, as does

```
        <img className="medium" src='/{product.image} alt={product.name} />
        <img className="medium" src={/{product.image}} alt={product.name} />
```

etc. I'm not sure how to make this work. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Please make sure to add some styles to your image tag like height and width.

Comment: I have the CSS set, it's less that, and changing a path. Ex: src={product.image} to src=" / {product.image}" or src="../ {product.image}

Comment: Did you try this syntax? 
<img src={require('./path/to/image/image.jpg')} />

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot do it that way, as it is looping over several dozen items. That would balloon my code from ten lines to over 1000.

Comment: Also you can use literal template as you asked for using /
src={`/${product.image}`}

It does not seem here but there is symbols.

Comment: Ahhh, I think that did it! The one I didn't try, of course. 


            <img className="medium" src={BACKTICK/{product.image}} alt={product.name}BACKTICK />


with the back ticks did work. Thank you!

Comment: Yeah :) Happy to help.
Also fyi, {BACKTICK/${product.image}BACKTICK} is proper usage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<img className="medium" src={`/${product.image}`} alt={product.name}/>
```

Answer (score 0):

For referencing local images you will need to import them like

```
import logo from './logo.png'; // Tell webpack this JS file uses this image

function Header() {
  // Import result is the URL of your image
  return <img src={logo} alt="Logo" />;
}
```

https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-images-fonts-and-files/

You can also see more details in this thread:
[How do I reference a local image in React?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39999367/how-do-i-reference-a-local-image-in-react)

Comment: Appreciate it! Unfortunately, it is looping over several dozen images, and I could not import them all. Thank you though!

Answer (score 0):

Here you have some ways to do this:

[image]

here is the code:

```html
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

function App() {
  const url = 'https://miro.medium.com/max/1920/1*hm7aE3BdUfUWUgBYK1GiZA.jpeg';
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        {/*From proyect files */}
        <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" width={400}/>  

         {/*From url on internet */}     
        <img src={url} className="App-logo" alt="logo"  width={400} />   

         {/*From public folder inside img folder */}    
        <img src='./img/react_image.jpg' className="App-logo" alt="logo"  width={400} />       
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```