# How to use an image in react imported from localhost

Tags: reactjs

So i'm working on a react project and i want to use an image which is stored in my computer
i made the following code

`<img src='my_image.png'/>`

however it doesn't show in the browser as shown below
[see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iB6I7.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I reference a local image in React?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39999367/how-do-i-reference-a-local-image-in-react)

Answer (score 0):

upload your images in your public folder then access it
eg:public/images/p1.png

```
<img src='images/p1.png'/>
```

https://codesandbox.io/embed/amazing-bouman-x3mnr?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark