# Logo does not change on scrolling using React

Tags: html, reactjs, event-listener

**Summary:**
I have this logo in my website header, I want this logo (image [1]) to change to another one (image [2]) on scrolling down, and to change back to the original logo (image [1]) when I scroll back to the top.

**What i tried:**
I tried to make it with `EventListener` and `useEffect` in the header page, but I'm getting this error below:

```
    ERROR in src\layouts\Navbar\index.jsx
    Line 12:3:  'listenScrollEvent' is not defined  no-undef
```

**My code:**

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { useEffect } from "react";


export default () => {

  useState = {
    imageSrc: '',
    imageAlt: ''
  }

  listenScrollEvent = e => {
    if (window.scrollY > 400) {
      this.setState({
        imageSrc: './/img/Smartlogger_logo.png',
        imageAlt: 'smartlogger white logo'
      })
    } else {
      this.setState({
        imageSrc: './../../views/Home/image/smartLoggerheader_logo.png',
        imageAlt: 'smartlogger colored logo'
      })
    }
  }

  
  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', this.listenScrollEvent)
  }, []);


  return (
    <header className='header-area header-sticky'>
      <div className='container'>
        <div className='row'>
          <div className='col-12'>
            <nav className='main-nav'>
              {/* ***** Logo Start ***** */}
              <a href='/#' className='logo'>
                <style>{css}</style>
                <img
                  src={this.setState}
                  alt='Smartlogger logo'
                />
              </a>
              {/* ***** Logo End ***** */}
              </nav>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </header>
      )
    }
```

Comment: Seems like you have udpated your question. previously you were using ```componentDidMount()```. I have answerd as per the initial details. you can modify it to functional component if you want to.

Comment: that's true, thanks for the quick help. imma test it now and reply with results in few minutes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `useState` hook you want to have your src and your alt.
Remember `useState` return an array of 2 elements, the first is the value and the second is the setter for that value.
You can use the setter in your `listenScrollEvent` function and you can use the value in your jsx.

You are also using a `css` variable in you jsx that isn't defined anywhere.

It should look something like this:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

export default () => {
    const [image, setImage] = useState({
        src: "",
        alt: "",
    });

    const listenScrollEvent = (e) => {
        if (window.scrollY > 400) {
            setImage({
                src: "../img/Smartlogger_white_logo.png",
                alt: "smartlogger white logo",
            });
        } else {
            setImage({
                src: "../img/Smartlogger_colored_logo.png",
                alt: "smartlogger colored logo",
            });
        }
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        window.addEventListener("scroll", listenScrollEvent);
    }, []);

    return (
        <header className="header-area header-sticky">
            <div className="container">
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="col-12">
                        <nav className="main-nav">
                            {/* ***** Logo Start ***** */}
                            <a href="/#" className="logo">
                                <style>{css}</style>
                                <img src={require(image.src)} alt={image.alt} />
                            </a>
                            {/* ***** Logo End ***** */}
                        </nav>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </header>
    );
};
```

An alternative solution that looks a little cleaner to me:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

import whiteLogo from "../img/Smartlogger_white_logo.png";
import coloredLogo from "../img/Smartlogger_colored_logo.png";

export default () => {
    const [isScrolled, setIsScrolled] = useState(false);

    const listenScrollEvent = (e) => setIsScrolled(window.scrollY > 400);

    useEffect(() => {
        window.addEventListener("scroll", listenScrollEvent);
    }, []);

    return (
        <header className="header-area header-sticky">
            <div className="container">
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="col-12">
                        <nav className="main-nav">
                            {/* ***** Logo Start ***** */}
                            <a href="/#" className="logo">
                                <style>{css}</style>
                                <img
                                    src={isScrolled ? whiteLogo : coloredLogo}
                                    alt={
                                        isScrolled
                                            ? "SmartLogger white logo"
                                            : "SmartLogger colored logo"
                                    }
                                />
                            </a>
                            {/* ***** Logo End ***** */}
                        </nav>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </header>
    );
};
```

EDIT: added note about `css` variable, fixed typo in code and formatted better

EDIT2: fixed image link and added the require in the `img` src attribute, this should fix the image loading

EDIT3: added alternative solution

Comment: thanks for the help, i'm testing your code, and i will provide with the feedback asap

Comment: Thanks again and i appreciate your help.
I recorded the results here : https://vimeo.com/687046894 .
As you can see, it works but the image doesn't want to load even though i checked the src path and it is correct
here a screenshot showing my files directory : https://ibb.co/5Mg8wJP

Comment: first: that path doesn't look correct to me. it should be "../img/Smartlogger_logo.png", it's 2 dots, 1 slash, not 1 dot 2 slashes :) second: try reading this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39999367/how-do-i-reference-a-local-image-in-react

Comment: Edited my previus solution to fix the image loading issue and added an alternative solution that looks cleaner to me

Answer (score 1):

You need to make the following changes in your code. It should fix the issue.

- Inside render() -  img src replace `src={this.setState}` with `src={this.state.imageSrc}`
- Inside `listenScrollEvent` function replace `window.scrollY`  with `event.srcElement.body.scrollY`

it will look like this (I have used random images here):

```
  listenScrollEvent = event => {
    if (event.srcElement.body.scrollY > 400) {
      this.setState({
        imageSrc: 'https://c.tenor.com/57w9du3NrV0AAAAS/css-html.gif',
        imageAlt: 'smartlogger white logo'
      })
    } else {
      this.setState({
        imageSrc: 'https://c.tenor.com/57w9du3NrV0AAAAS/css-html.gif',
        imageAlt: 'smartlogger colored logo'
      })
    }
  }
```

**Full working code :** (I have added style={{height:'200vh'}} on container div just to test it on my local. You can remove it)

```js
import React from 'react'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'

export default class App extends React.Component {

state = {
    imageSrc: 'https://c.tenor.com/TReUojNlZ6wAAAAi/js-javascript.gif',
    imageAlt: ''
  }

  listenScrollEvent = event => {
    if (event.srcElement.body.scrollY > 400) {
      this.setState({
        imageSrc: 'https://c.tenor.com/57w9du3NrV0AAAAS/css-html.gif',
        imageAlt: 'smartlogger white logo'
      })
    } else {
      this.setState({
        imageSrc: 'https://c.tenor.com/57w9du3NrV0AAAAS/css-html.gif',
        imageAlt: 'smartlogger colored logo'
      })
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', this.listenScrollEvent)
  }

  render() {
  return (
    <header className='header-area header-sticky'>
      <div className='container' style={{height:"200vh"}}>
        <div className='row'>
          <div className='col-12'>
            <nav className='main-nav'>
              {/* ***** Logo Start ***** */}
              <a href='/#' className='logo'>
                {/* <style>{css}</style> */}
                <img
                  src={this.state.imageSrc}
                  alt='Smartlogger logo'
                />
              </a>
              {/* ***** Logo End ***** */}
          </nav>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </header>
  )
  }
}
```

Hope that's how you wanted it to work. Try running it on your local and then you can modify it as per your requiremnets.

Comment: i tried your code but the error `'listenScrollEvent' is not defiefined` still persist

Comment: Here the full view of my code https://ibb.co/WBKP0hN

Comment: looking into it. till then you can check mine working code here - https://jsfiddle.net/Lrsc3nyj/.

Comment: I approve, that actually works like i expected, hmm i dont understand why listenscrollevent still not defined in my local though...

Comment: @dark can you try removing ```this``` keyword from ```this.listenScrollEvent```? as you are using a functional component now. And update listenScrollEvent  to an arrow function like ```const listenScrollEvent  = (event) => { // code//} ```

Comment: the error has gone (no more errors) but my localhost in the browser shows a totally white page.

Comment: i hope this new screenshot helps https://ibb.co/q7N9zwY

Comment: the issue is in the usage of usetate hook (usestate always return an array of 2 elemtents but in your case it's only one) @coglialoro has mentioned it in his answer. please have a look