# Local images will not display on my react app

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

Web urls work, local path images work as background images. But, local path images WONT work using img tag.

[use case](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UFL71.png)

```
       <div class="Gallery">
  <div class="ItemOne">
     <img src="images/witcher.jpg" alt="ImageOne"></img>
  </div>
  <div class="ItemTwo">2</div>
  <div class="ItemThree">3</div>
  <div class="ItemFour">4</div>
```

Comment: Does this answer to your question? https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-images-fonts-and-files/

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39999367/how-do-i-reference-a-local-image-in-react

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I reference a local image in React?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39999367/how-do-i-reference-a-local-image-in-react)

Answer (score 2):

Import the image first

```
import ImageOne from 'images/witcher.jpg'
```

and use it this way

```
<img src={ImageOne} alt="ImageOne"></img>
```