# Rendering multiple images using Props in React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props, react-component, imageurl

I am trying to render images in my local system to a website using react components. In the "index.js" file I am creating 4 different components with attributes. One of the attributes is the "img". In the "Card.js" file I have created a card component and want to render this 4 times on the page. But, I am unable to link the image to the component properly hence it's not loading. I have attached the screenshots and the relevant code below.

[Component that I need to render multiple times using props](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HzAaq.png)

[Index.js file where I am passing props to components](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3LPMs.png)

Comment: are you importing the image

Comment: No, I wasn't. But thanks now it's working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should import the image, using

```
<Card img={require('./mj.jpg')} />
```

or

```
import mj from './mj.jpg';

<Card img={mj} />
```

Some reference: [How do I reference a local image in React?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39999367/how-do-i-reference-a-local-image-in-react)

Comment: Thanks, man. I am fairly new to React and these small things can get very confusing sometimes