# Can't Display Image using .find() in ReactJs

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, create-react-app, react-dom

I can't display selected item image only alt are in display.

App.js

```
 <Route path="/Item/:id" element={<Item />} />
```

This is my MUI styled Link Trending.js

```
  <StyledLink to={"/Item/" + item._id}>
            <Stack>
              <ItemName>{item.name}</ItemName>
              <Typography>Brand: {item.brand}</Typography>
            </Stack>
          </StyledLink>
```

This is my Item.js I can display the item.name and item.brands but I can't display image only alts

```
 import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
   import items from "../../items";

const Item = () => {
  let { id } = useParams();
  const item = items.find((item) => item._id === id);
  console.log(item);
  return (
    <>
      <Stack sx={{ backgroundColor: "skyblue", height: "900px" }}>
        <Stack>
          <Stack sx={{ width: "250px", height: "400px" }}>
            <img src={item.image} alt={item.brand} loading="lazy" />
          </Stack>
        </Stack>
        <Stack>{item.price}</Stack>
      </Stack>
    </>
  );
};

export default Item;
```

This is the results of my console.log and element

```
{_id: '2', name: 'Headset', image: './images/headset3.jpg', description: 'Noise Cancelling Headset', brand: 'Hyper', …}
brand: "Hyper"
category: "Computer"
countInStock: 1030
description: "Noise Cancelling Headset"
image: "./images/headset3.jpg"
name: "Headset"
numReviews: 169
preSalePrice: 96
price: 98.6
rating: 4.5
_id: "2"
[[Prototype]]: Object
```

[HtmlElement Image Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1NAQp.png)

this is my items.js

```
const items = [
  {
    _id: "1",
    name: "Keyboard",
    image: "./images/keyboard2.jpg",
    description: "High-Tech Keyboard",
    brand: "Monster",
    category: "Computer",
    price: 300,
    preSalePrice: 300,
    countInStock: 688,
    rating: 4,
    numReviews: 100,
  },
  {
    _id: "2",
    name: "Headset",
    image: "./images/headset3.jpg",
    description: "Noise Cancelling Headset",
    brand: "Hyper",
    category: "Computer",
    price: 98.6,
    preSalePrice: 96,
    countInStock: 1030,
    rating: 4.5,
    numReviews: 169,
  },
];

export default items;
```

and this the result I got I don't know what's going on here. I also change width and height of img but nothing happen. Thank you

[Result Item.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vdG6b.png)

Comment: Are these images on your local filesystem or a remote server?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I reference a local image in React?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39999367/how-do-i-reference-a-local-image-in-react)

Comment: Images are under my Public Folder and items.js are on component folder..

Answer (score 0):

You need to import the images before you can use them.

In your `items` file, you'll need to import them like so and add the result of the import to each item in the array:

```
import HeadSet from './images/headset3.jpg'

// stuff

[
  // modify each item in array to do same
  {
    _id: "2",
    name: "Headset",
    image: HeadSet,
    description: "Noise Cancelling Headset",
    brand: "Hyper",
    category: "Computer",
    price: 98.6,
    preSalePrice: 96,
    countInStock: 1030,
    rating: 4.5,
    numReviews: 169,
  },
]
```

Comment: Compiled with problems:X

ERROR in ./src/items.js 3:0-44

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './images/headset3.jpg'    I got error

Comment: You'll need to change the path to match where the image is -- I dont know your folder structure so cant help there. Its probably a bunch of directories up.

Comment: Thanks Adam. But its working in mapping it. but image is not working if Im using .find() to display selected item it only display the names but image :(    https://stackoverflow.com/a/73268926/9109985

Answer (score 0):

But it works using .map() in Trending.Js

```
import items from "../../items";
    <StackImages direction="row">
          {items.map((item) => (
            <StackImg key={item._id}>
              <img src={item.image} alt={item.name} />
    
              <StyledLink to={"/Item/" + item._id}>
                <Stack>
                  <ItemName>{item.name}</ItemName>
                  <Typography>Brand: {item.brand}</Typography>
                </Stack>
              </StyledLink>
    
           
            </StackImg>
          ))}
          {/* End of Image List */}
    
        </StackImages>
```

This is the result in Trending.js its working [.Map() array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/09tyT.png)

but if I select item it will redirect to Item.js and Im using .find() id to display item..