# Why doesn't my image work in React when I hard-code the path?

Tags: reactjs

So when i import the img
Example:

```
import Logo from "../images/logo.png"

            <img src={Logo}/>
```

it works but when I do the path only in src it doesnt work at all:

```
<img src"../images/logo.png"/>
```

and im new to react so idk how to use props in the import way like
<img src={`../images/${props.img}`} />
but when i update the img to app.js im trying for at least 2 hours but i cant find the solution how to fix it cuz it doesnt show the img

Comment: What's your question? The former is the correct way and the latter isn't. That behavior is expected. Please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I reference a local image in React?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39999367/how-do-i-reference-a-local-image-in-react)