# Why my image is not display in category products page in React.js

Tags: html, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I have to display the relevant products on clicking the specific category. When products page open product image is not shown. Otherwise other elements are shown paragraph tags etc. Here is my code.

`MenuCategory` page, where my categories of dishes are displaying, on clicking of each category, it opens the products, and its image not shown.

```
import React from "react";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import { menu } from "../../Data";

const MenuCategory = () => {
  const { category } = useParams();

  function convertToSlug(text){
    return text.toLowerCase().replace(/ /g, '-').replace(/[^\w-]+/g,'');
  }

  // Find the category object in the menu data that matches the URL parameter
  const selectedCategory = menu.find(
    (menuCategory) => convertToSlug(menuCategory.category) === category    
  );

  // Check if the category was found, and if so, retrieve its products
  const categoryProducts = selectedCategory ? selectedCategory.products : [];
  console.log(categoryProducts);

  return (
    <>
      <div className="container">
        <h2>{category}</h2>
        <div className="row mt-5">
          {categoryProducts.map((asianFood, index) => (
            <div className="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12" key={index}>
              <img src={asianFood.img2} alt="" onError={(e) => e.target.src = "/path-to-placeholder-image.jpg"} />
              <p>{asianFood.title}</p>
              <p>{asianFood.price}</p>
            </div>
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default MenuCategory;
```

```
<Route path='/menu/:category' element={<MenuCategory />} />
```

```js
export const menu = [
  {
    category: "Asian Food",
    img: "images/menu/asianfusion-1-300x300.jpg",
    products: [
      {
        img2: "images/menu/Asian/blackpepperasian.jpg",
        title: "Black Pepper Asian",
        price: "1500",
      },
      {
        img2: "images/menu/Asian/chickenchillidry-300x300.jpg",
        title: "Chicken Chilli Dry",
        price: "1800",
      },
      // Add more Asian Food products here
    ],
  },
  {
    category: "Continental Food",
    products: [
      // Add Continental Food products here
    ],
  },
  // Add other categories and their products here
];
```

```
import React from "react";
import { menu } from "../../Data";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

const Menu = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <div className="container">
        <h1>Menu</h1>
        <div className="row mt-5">
          {menu.map((category) => (
            <div className="col-lg-4 col-md-3 col-sm-12" key={category.category}>
              <Link to={`/menu/${category.category.toLowerCase().replace(/\s+/g, '-')}`}>
                <img src={category.img} alt="" />
                <p className="mt-3">{category.category}</p>
              </Link>
            </div>
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default Menu;
```

My img not shown

```
<img src={asianFood.img2} alt="" onError={(e) => e.target.src = "/path-to-placeholder-image.jpg"} />
```

but below tags are shown

```
<p>{asianFood.title}</p>
<p>{asianFood.price}</p>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I reference a local image in React?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39999367/how-do-i-reference-a-local-image-in-react)

Comment: In case you just missed or forgotten it, or haven't taken the full [tour], there are 100% completely optional actions one can take after [someone answers](/help/someone-answers) that helps rate and curate content on the site.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that the image URLs ***always*** use an absolute path to the `images` directory in the public directory. Absolute paths start with a leading `"/"` character. The difference between them is telling the browser to start from "root" or to start from a relative directory based on the current URL path. You want the one that starts from the root of the public directory.

```js
export const menu = [
  {
    category: "Asian Food",
    img: "/images/menu/asianfusion-1-300x300.jpg", // <-- absolute path
    products: [
      {
        img2: "/images/menu/Asian/blackpepperasian.jpg", // <-- absolute path
        title: "Black Pepper Asian",
        price: "1500",
      },
      {
        img2: "/images/menu/Asian/chickenchillidry-300x300.jpg", // <-- absolute path
        title: "Chicken Chilli Dry",
        price: "1800",
      },
      // Add more Asian Food products here
    ],
  },
  {
    category: "Continental Food",
    products: [
      // Add Continental Food products here
    ],
  },
  // Add other categories and their products here
];
```

Comment: Yeah, That's solved. Thank you Drew.

Comment: @user3653784 Welcome, glad to help. Cheers and good luck!