# I can not show an image using react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm triying to show an image using react, but i don't know why it did not works.

First, I created this component:
This is the component:

```
import React from "react";


function Tarjeta (){
    return(
      <div className="tarjeta-jugador">
        <h1 className="nombre-jugador">Alvaro Montero</h1>
        <img className={require('../imagenes/montero.jpg')} alt='Foto Montero' />
      </div>
    )
}
export default Tarjeta;
```

And This is how I'm triying to render it,

```
import './App.css';
import Tarjeta from './componentes/Tarjeta'

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Tarjeta />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

[This is how it looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BMEhe.png)

I want to know why is not working and how may i show it, usgin this sintaxis. My path is correct.

Comment: Why are you requiring images, instead of just linking its `src` to the relative URL where the image lives, in your asset folder? Why make things so much harder than it needs to be? And with that said: you're using `className` instead of `src`.

Comment: Here is the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47487760/6588498

Answer (score 0):

The `<img>` element must have a [src](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img#src) attribute. Without it, no image will render. The `src` attribute must be a URL to an image which the browser can download, which means your image must be served by a file server. This isn't always set up automatically, but if your project has a `public` directory you may be able to put the image file there. For example, if you copied the file to `public/imagenes/montero.jpg` you might be able to use a path like so:

```html
<img src='/imagenes/montero.jpg' alt='Foto Montero' />
```

In your code you're trying to call `require` with a local file path to an image. With certain bundler plugins it's sometimes possible to embed a base64 text version of the image into the `src` attribute, but I'm not sure that's what you're trying to accomplish here.