# How to use static images in a React Application?

Tags: reactjs, webpack

This could be a trivial question. I was using base64 but my code is getting cluttered. I need to load background images. from the filesystem there's no other way. I am using react with typescript and Webpack if it's relavant.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I reference a local image in React?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39999367/how-do-i-reference-a-local-image-in-react)

Answer (score 0):

Public:

- Keep your images in `public/img` folder - like `public/img/aishwarya.jpg`.

In your component if you want load an image say, inside an Img tag, write so:

- `<img src="img/aishwarya.jpg" />`

Your images will be loaded // just remember you need to put your image in the public folder. I recommend make an `img` folder and keep all images there.

Say, you want to use it as background image in a div, so write:

```
import React from "react";
import './Ex4.css';

export default function Ex4() {

    return (
        <div>
           <div style={{background: "url('img/aishwarya.jpg')"}}>Sample Div </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```