# Using React linking images inside of components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I am learning react. I have a file `website_index.js` inside my components folder inside my src folder. Also inside my src folder is an images folder. I am trying to link pictures in a carousel to the pictures in the image folder but no matter what path I enter it does not find them. Is it impossible to display these pictures?

Will someone please tell me the proper way to do this.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Jumbotron, Carousel } from 'react-bootstrap';

class Home extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <Jumbotron>
      <Carousel>
        <Carousel.Item>
          <img width={900} height={500} alt="900x500" src="./images/Ian_FMD_400.jpg"/>
          <Carousel.Caption>
            <h3>First slide label</h3>
            <p>Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue mollis interdum.</p>
          </Carousel.Caption>
        </Carousel.Item>
        <Carousel.Item>
          <img width={900} height={500} alt="900x500" src="../images/Ian_FMD_400.jpg"/>
          <Carousel.Caption>
            <h3>Second slide label</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
          </Carousel.Caption>
        </Carousel.Item>
        <Carousel.Item>
          <img width={900} height={500} alt="900x500" src="./src/images/Ian_FMD_400.jpg"/>
          <Carousel.Caption>
            <h3>Third slide label</h3>
            <p>Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur.</p>
          </Carousel.Caption>
        </Carousel.Item>
      </Carousel>
      </Jumbotron>
    );
  }
}

export default Home;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Correct path for img on React.js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37644265/correct-path-for-img-on-react-js)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**One quick and clean approach is to import the image the same way you would import or `require()` a module:**

```
import image1 from './path/to/image';
```

**And then reference that image from JSX:**

```
<img width={900} height={500} alt="" src={image1} />
```

The path to the image might be auto-resolved for you, depending on how your bundler (webpack, etc) is setup.

On the other hand, if you aren't importing the image the same way you import a module (and you are referencing the image path directly inline from JSX or a component), you don't need to prepend the image `src` with `./` (because it's not an import, it's just a regular relative path), so just write your *inline* `src` calls to point to the image **the same way you would write it in HTML** (where the path equals the **relative** path back to the images directory *relative* to the HTML file):

So this:

```
<img width={900} height={500} alt="" src="./src/images/Ian_FMD_400.jpg" />
```

Might be:

```
<img width={900} height={500} alt="" src="images/Ian_FMD_400.jpg" />
```

So just to recap, two different in the two ways to import an image:

```
// option one (imports)
import image1 from './path/to/image/relative/to/COMPONENT';
<img src={image1} />

// option two (relative paths inline)
<img src="path/to/image/relative/to/HTML" />
```

---

You might also get some clues by reading: [Correct path for img on React.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37644265/correct-path-for-img-on-react-js)

Answer (score 2):

Well, you said:

> "... I have a file website_index.js inside my components folder inside my src folder."

You also said:

> "...Also inside my src folder is an images folder."

So, your project structure is something like that:

src
|_ components
|_ images

Try this:

```
<img width={900} height={500} alt="900x500"  src={require('../images/Ian_FMD_400.jpg')}/>
```

Comment: Are you using any task runner like "webpack" or "gulp"?

Comment: Ok, often when we are developing some application, with react, or angular, or some other framework, we use some task runner such as "webpack" and "gulp". Then, this task runner take care about how to build our production (or public folder), for us. For more information visit https://webpack.github.io/docs/  

If you want to see this in the real world, you can check out this project using React and Webpack to build the "production" version.  https://github.com/darde/RD-Book-Store