# How to reference a pdf file in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, single-page-application, filepath

I have a Reactjs SPA whose file structure looks like this:

[image]

In that app there's a simple component (**Resume.js**) where I want the users to be able to see/download a pdf file within the browser (**resume_english.pdf**). However I haven't been able to do this neither locally nor in GitHub pages where I plan on hosting the SPA. It always redirects me to the homepage.

**Resume.js** looks like this:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

class Resume extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {};
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className={'resume-container'}>
                <div id={'resume-pdf'}>You can view, download and print my résumé in pdf format in <a
                    href={'./public/resume_english.pdf'}>English</a> and <a href={'#'}>Spanish</a></div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Resume;
```

Any ideas on what might be wrong on how to solve it? I already tried importing like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39946404/4838227), but didn't work.

Answer (score 5):

Looks like this was made with create-react-app. If so, files in the `public` directory will be copied to `build`, and the `build` directory will serve as the root directory for your site. So the appropriate href is `/resume_english.pdf`.

Just try to enter the url directly in the browser. Something like `http://localhost:3000/resume_english.pdf` or `https://danielsto.github.io/resume_english.pdf`

Comment: It works locally, but not on GitHub Pages. Having `href={/resume_english.pdf}` leads to `https://danielsto.github.io/resume_english.pdf`, i.e. `Site not found`. Repository is private, could that be part of the problem?

Comment: https://help.github.com/articles/configuring-a-publishing-source-for-github-pages/

Comment: Depends on how the github pages repo is configured. You can use a relative url `./resume_english.pdf` if it's a project page (danielsto.github.io/reponame) and not a user page (danielsto.github.io)