# Trying to read images from .json file in create-react-app

Tags: javascript, reactjs

[image]

I am trying to load a image from my .json file into my component, but the image does not load.

[Someone looks to have solved it, but I don't know what he is talking about in terms of "branching"](https://www.reddit.com/r/reactjs/comments/5gq41r/importing_an_image_from_a_local_json_file/)

```js
  "Bumper": [{
      "id": 1,
      "productSquareId": "BumperStubby",
      "productImage": "bumper",
      "companyImage": "logo.png",
      "price": "$55.99"
    },
```

```js
const image1 = ProductInformation.Bumper[0].companyImage;
<img  className = "MainImage" src ={image1}/>
```

My images is in the same folder(components) as my components. What am I doing wrong here? I appreciate your time.

Comment: are you closing your array at the end ????

Comment: yes. I was just giving a snippet.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like I solved my question, but by making my .json file a .js file.

`<img  className = "MainImage" src ={bumper[0].productImage}/>`

```js
export const bumper = [
  {
    id: 1,
    productSquareId: 'BumperStubby',
    productImage: require('./bumper1.png'),
    companyImage: require('./logo.png'),
    price: '$55.99',

  }
]
```

Is there any performance difference in using a .js file than a .json file?

Comment: Nice one. Followed your logic and got it working for me

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried just putting a slash in front of the image name
I think you can find a few solutions here:
[Correct path for img on React.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37644265/correct-path-for-img-on-react-js)

The quickest one that may work is using require like so:

```
<img  className = "MainImage" src ={require(image1)}/>
```