# Image URL is taking both localhost and server host

Tags: reactjs

While accessing the image from the API, I am getting the below URL : http://localhost:3000/example.com/uploads/catalog/product_Milk-26_1538031521.jpeg .

This URL is taking both local and server hosts.

Thanks!

Comment: so how do you access the image? can you please post that code

Comment: for (let j = 0; j < product_list.length; j++) {
      console.log(product_list[j]);
      let pp = product_list[j];
        <img src={pp.image} className="imagestyle" />
         }

Comment: Getting error in the line line : <img src={pp.image} className="imagestyle" />

Comment: @Deepti put the code in the question and also share product_list data in the question and also specify the error details

Comment: have a look on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37644265/correct-path-for-img-on-react-js) answer