# how to use java-script variable in a style.css file

Tags: css, reactjs

I need to access the public folder /images folder in reactjs. since we have jsx I was able to access that in the following the way

```
let x= window.location.origin + '/image/myimage.jpg';
```

However, I need to access the same folder inside app.css

```
.breadcum-header {
    height: 25vh;
    background-image: url('../../../public/img/myimage.jpg')

}
```

I'm getting the following error when I try to do so. is there any alternative way?

[image]

Comment: are you using create react app ?

Comment: yes i'm using create react app

Comment: Depending on whether you are working on dev or prod, you can control different parameters, take a look at the [documentation](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables#adding-development-environment-variables-in-env), it should help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Correct path for img on React.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37644265/correct-path-for-img-on-react-js)