# Image Only Shows When Given a Link, Not a Path

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to show an image on my website and am having way more trouble than I feel like I should. I've done this multiple times with no issue on other projects but for some reason its not working.

HTML:
`<img src="./reddit.png"/>`

My image IS in the same folder as my html file.

What I've Tried

`<img src="./reddit.png"/>`

`<img src="reddit.png"/>`

`<img src="../reddit.png"/>`

`<img src="D:project\src\components\reddit.png"/>`

`<img src="D:project/src/components/reddit.png"/>`

I thought maybe it was an issue with the tag so I tried,

`<img src="https://faroutmagazine.co.uk/static/uploads/2020/02/George-Harrison-Let-It-Be-768x464.jpg"/>`

and that img showed up fine. I also tried moving the img to a images folder and making the path "/images/reddit.png" but that also didn't work.

(also I am in a js react component if that has an effect on the HTML)

Comment: Are you sure the image extension is the extension you loaded? Also, check if you have permission to the folder containing the images

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Correct path for img on React.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37644265/correct-path-for-img-on-react-js)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `<img src="/src/components/reddit.png"/>`, alternatively use the `import` keyword for relative paths:

`import reddit from './reddit.png';`

Comment: Thank you using  ```import reddit from './reddit.png';``` and ```<img src={ reddit }/>``` did the trick.