# Cannot load images from my desktop on React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image, load

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kLkJu.png)I have a folder Images on my desktop with .jpg and .svg on my src file that I would like to add on a component but I cannot load them. I don't understand what I'm doing wrong. Can someone help?

```js
import React from 'react';
import './Banner.css';








const Banner = () => {

 
 
        return (

            

            <div className="banner">
                     <img src="../Images/banner.bg.jpg" alt="banner" />
              
                <div className="text">
                    <img src='../Images/party-icon.svg' alt="party" />
             <h3>Let's The Fun Begin!</h3>
            <p>Thanks for your order, we'll have it with you as soon as possible.<br></br>
               Your order number is #10293838 and a confirmation email has been sent to the address provided.</p>

            <p>Order Even Faster in Future</p>
            

            
            <button className="button">CREATE AN ACCOUNT</button>

         
           
            </div>

            
           
            </div>
          
        );
    
}

export default Banner;
```

Comment: try importing the folder inside your project, probably the relative path of the images is not what you are expecting

Comment: If your file is x/y/z/index.html then your browser security settings might not allow it to load images like x/y/image.jpeg.

Try organizing things so x/y/z/index.html is above your images, like x/y/z/images/pic.jpeg.

Comment: Can you show the screenshot of your current project tree? Maybe the path is wrong and you are too tried to realised it :D

Comment: Are you using create-react-app or you wrote the webpack configuration on your own?

Comment: Yes I'm using create-react-app. I've added a screenshot of the project tree if that can help

Comment: the folder Images is already inside my project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can import those separate images & use it on `src`, or you can use `require`.

If you place your `Images` directory inside public folder then you can access your images directly like this

```html
 src="/Images/banner.bg.jpg"
```

Check the answers of this question ([Correct path for img on React.js](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37644265/7344409)), I think that may help you to understand those solutions better.

Answer (score 0):

1 - Your images should sit inside your project source (usually in a  '`assets`'/'`images`') folder.

2 - Make sure that the source path in `<img src='../Images/party-icon.svg' alt="party" />` is relative to the current file and points to the party-icon.svg sitting in your assets folder.

Comment: yes I put them inside the project source in an Images folder

Answer (score 0):

You may import the pic on top like this:

```
import bg from '../Images/banner.bg.jpg'
```

then add your pic like this:

`<img src={bg} alt="banner" />`

you can do the same thing for other pics. Instead of bg you can write anything you want. Choosing appropriate names for different pictures can be better.

Good luck :)

Comment: that's not working either, when I do this now it says Module not found: Can't resolve '../Images/banner.bg.jpg' in '/Users/cihemzine/Fisheye/client/src/components'