# Image doesn't appear in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm creating a mini project in React, I have an issue in the following code;

```
function Medwiki(props) {
    const medicines = [
        { name: 'Medicine A ', details: 'Details of Medicine A', image: '../assets/pngegg.png' },
        { name: 'Medicine B ', details: 'Details of Medicine B', image: 'https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/z/medicine-capsule-logo-vector-illustration-medicine-capsule-logo-file-format-can-be-scaled-to-any-size-141357083.jpg' },
        { name: 'Medicine C ', details: 'Details of Medicine C', image: 'https://example.com/medicineC.jpg' },
        { name: 'Medicine C',  details: 'Details of Medicine C', image: 'https://example.com/medicineC.jpg' },
        { name: 'Medicine C',  details: 'Details of Medicine C', image: 'https://example.com/medicineC.jpg' },
        { name: 'Medicine C',  details: 'Details of Medicine C', image: 'https://example.com/medicineC.jpg' },
        { name: 'Medicine C',  details: 'Details of Medicine C', image: 'https://example.com/medicineC.jpg' },
      ];
    return (
        <div>
        <div className="top-container">
        MedWiki
        <img src='https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/z/medicine-capsule-logo-vector-illustration-medicine-capsule-logo-file-format-can-be-scaled-to-any-size-141357083.jpg' alt="Logo" style={{ width: '10px', height: '10px' }}/>
        </div>
        <div className="medicine-container">
          {medicines.map((medicine, index) => (
            <div className="medicine-box" key={index}>
              <img src={medicine.image} alt={medicine.name} />
              <div className="medicine-name">{medicine.name}</div>
              <div className="medicine-details">{medicine.details}</div>
            </div>
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

For Medicine A, the image doesn't appear, but for the web link it works as in Medicine B

the path for my .js file is src/files and for the image is /src/pngegg.png

What might be the issue?

Comment: Try to use this way: image: require('../assets/pngegg.png')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might not be able to resolve the path of the image. I think you can give it a try with `require('path/to/image/')`

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use relative path relative to root directory
for example "/src/assets/pngegg.png"

Check this question here
[Correct path for img on React.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37644265/correct-path-for-img-on-react-js)

may give you more clear answers

Answer (score 0):

I think that the issue is to use a relative path **'../assets/pngegg.png'**

Try a absolute path instead:

**'https://{myprojectaddress}/assets/pngegg.png'**

Answer (score 0):

There is some differences using image in React.
Please follow this post.
https://levelup.gitconnected.com/display-images-in-react-8ff1f5b1cf9a?gi=6a512c107c6a
Hope you this will be helpful to you.