# react mapping over an array with image url

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am trying to map over an array with some image urls
However I am having trouble to display the images

this is my mapping function

```html
<div className='Team-Members'>
    {OurTeamtext.map((team)=>{
    return (
        <div key={team.id} className='Team-Member'>
            <img src={team.picture}></img>

            <div className='Team-Member-description'>
            <p>{team.name}</p>
            <p>{team.position}</p>
          </div>
        </div>
    )
    })}
    </div>
```

and this is the array

```js
export const OurTeamtext = [
    {
        id:1,
        name:'Sebastian',
        position:'Founder and CEO',
        picture:'../images/Sebastian.png'
    },
    {
        id:2,
        name:'Felix Merz',
        position:'Founder and CEO',
        picture:'sebastian'
    },
    {
        id:3,
        name:'Felix Merz',
        position:'Founder and CEO',
        picture:'sebastian'
    }
```

everything else then the image url can be displayed
Can somebody help me??

I tryed alredy different URL
It looks like it will not work
Can somebody help me please

Comment: Could you update your code example? It seems you are missing some of it when you copied it over. Because of that it looks like you don't even have an `<img>` tag to display the images.

Comment: Try `src={require(team.picture)}`

Comment: It seems like your issue has already been addressed at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37644265/correct-path-for-img-on-react-js)

Answer (score 1):

In **create-react-app** relative paths for images don't seem to work. Instead, you can import an image:

```
import Sebastian from '../images/Sebastian.png'; // relative path to image

export const OurTeamtext = [
    {
        id:1,
        name:'Sebastian',
        position:'Founder and CEO',
        picture: Sebastian
    },
    {
        id:2,
        name:'Felix Merz',
        position:'Founder and CEO',
        picture: Sebastian
    },
    {
        id:3,
        name:'Felix Merz',
        position:'Founder and CEO',
        picture: Sebastian
    }
    ...
```

This answer was taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37644265/correct-path-for-img-on-react-js). Your issue has already been addressed.

Answer (score 0):

I just replaced the images url with the hosted images urls and it worked out for me , You can check the [codesandbox here](https://codesandbox.io/s/maping-issue-forked-wcx8qw?file=/src/data.js:0-427)

```js
export const OurTeamtext = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "Sebastian",
    position: "Founder and CEO",
    picture: "https://picsum.photos/id/237/200/300"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "Felix Merz",
    position: "Founder and CEO",
    picture: "https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/200/300"
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: "Felix Merz",
    position: "Founder and CEO",
    picture: "https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/200/300"
  }
];
```